# Opening current directory with explorer within file manager ranger (WSL)

Tags: linux, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ranger

I'm using WSL and i want a keybinding to  opening windows explorer on the current directory path within ranger (file manager (https://github.com/ranger/ranger).

In the shell i can open a explorer instance in the current folder with `explorer.exe .` I tried to achieve that with the keybinding `map ge shell explorer.exe "%d"` but it only opens the explorer instance with a path to the documents folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Requirements: WSL2 (wslpath is needed [for reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17046)

> map ge shell explorer.exe $(wslpath -w %d)